# Open fully quitted app from URL scheme did not call the function from postNotificationName in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

Here I have set the code for URL scheme:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if let userUrl = String(url) as String? {
        print("\(userUrl)")
        if (userUrl == "count://fromClipBoard") {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("com.getContentFromClipBoard", object: self)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And add the following code to my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setContentFromClipBoard", name: "com.getContentFromClipBoard", object: nil)

    //............
}

func setContentFromClipBoard() {
    tv.text = "WAHAHA"

    if let clipBoard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string {
        tv.text = clipBoard
    }
}
```

And when my app is not fully quitted, `com.getContentFromClipBoard` called well and `tv.text` become `clipBoard`.

However, when I fully quit the app and then use this URL scheme, the `com.getContentFromClipBoard` isn't get called and `tv.text` remain empty.

So how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: how do you want to fix it? the view doesn't exist yet. are you going to present it specifically, or store the details so it can update itself when it does appear?

Comment: @Wain `ViewController` view is the initial view of the app

Comment: are you also checking the launch options and using them ?

Comment: @Wain what do you mean? The app is opening from URL `count://fromClipBoard`

Comment: Is `application:openURL:options:
` called? Have you implemented `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and what does it do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by checking `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` too inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

(Delaying is waiting the view to load)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let userUrl = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if (userUrl.absoluteString == "count://fromClipBoard") {
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("com.getContentFromClipBoard", object: self)
            }
        })
    }
}
```